# I can't update flutter

Tags: flutter, upgrade

I run the flutter upgrade command.
And the following error pops up:

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/beta': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/beta': reference broken
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
 ! [new branch]            beta       -> origin/beta  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/master': reference broken
 ! [new branch]            master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

Comment: Have you tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling? From the message, something is broken.

Comment: @tomerpacific No, how can I do it?

Comment: @tomerpacific Completely remove flutter and download over again?

Comment: Yes, I would try that. Make sure to use the stable version of flutter.

Comment: @tomerpacific I have a stable version

Comment: @tomerpacific Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows that the local version of your Flutter repo is broken. To solve this, you have to completely delete the current Flutter SDK you have and download a new one.